# rules for matching a "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value"

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to know what rules are used to determine what is a potentially dangerous form value so that I can write client side validation to prevent it hitting the server. Ideally I would like to know how the framework determines what is a potentially dangerous combination of characters, so I could use the same rules in my custom validator to prevent them ever hitting the server.

Comment: Not exactly a rule but using *Prepared Statements* usually reduces the chance of having a client submit a set of *special* characters that could potentially jeopardize your database.

Comment: not just your database, not sure how <script> tags would jeopardize your database for example

Comment: You could process the text you are being submitted and remove any special characters.

Comment: @bluntstone,  `<script>` tags wouldn't jeoperdize you database but that shall allow cross site scripting threats to your webApp.

Comment: yeah i know that's what i was saying allowing script tags has nothing to with the db

Comment: exactly @npinti but what are those special characters, what does the framework use to determine what they are

Comment: I was essentially looking for this: [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744002/asp-net-potentially-dangerous-request-javascript-regex

Answer (score 2):

**Reasons:**

1. This error is generally arised when a `valid html` is entered in text input. i.e. with **opening and closing** html tags `<****>`.
2. It is also caused due to entering html entites like `&nbsp;` `&amp;` `&lt;` `&gt;` `&quot;` etc.
3. In simple words You can say that if `text-input` contains some symbols like **">, &, <, ="**; etc, it will be recognized as dangerous value.

**For resolving You can use:**

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
</system.web>
```

in your **web.config** to validate such inputs.

**OR**

You can **[htmlencode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz.aspx)** the input using:

```
String clean_value = Server.HtmlEncode(TextBox1.Text);
```

**Following Articles may help you:**

**[How To Catch HttpRequestValidationException](http://romsteady.blogspot.com/2007/06/how-to-catch-httprequestvalidationexcep.html)**

**http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/mswinswdev/ms_vbnet_server_error_potentially_dangerous.htm**

**[A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client)**

Hope this helps.

Comment: I actually don't want to do that, I know I can switch off the validation or switch it on I am more concerned about what is considered a potentially dangerous form value. I know the obvious ones like <script or <!-- but I would like to know the ones I am not thinking about, if the framework was open source, I would like to look at the code that raises that error

Comment: @bluntstone Html entities mainly cause this error. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The validateRequest = false is generally not recommended. This is what I did:

On the server side, you can use this:

Create a hidden field in asp.net and encode it.

```
hiddenFieldMessage.Value = Uri.EscapeDataString(dangerousString);
```

Then in Javascript, create a text area and decode the encoded value.

```
<script>
    (function () {
        
        const content = document.getElementById('<%= hiddenFieldMessage.ClientID %>').value;
        // decode the content back to html
        var textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
        textArea.innerHTML = decodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('<%= hiddenFieldMessage.ClientID %>').value);
        const content = textArea.value;  // decoded value
   })
```

This way, there is no need to switch off the validation (which will make your webpage vulnerable to injection attacks)